# Yes/No nullable column on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, column, list-form

Is there a way to add a nullable by default Yes/No column on SharePoint list item?

Displayed as non-checked radios [ ] Yes [ ] No, or grayed/undefined checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set null value to SharePoint default Yes/No columns and show it as radio buttons. By default a Yes/No column appears as a single check box.

**Workaround/Suggestion**:

If you want non-checked radio buttons with Yes and No options, I will suggest you to create a "Choice" column with column settings like:

[image]

**Output on list form**:

[image]

---

If you want to use Yes/No column only and show radio buttons, you have to customize your list form using Power apps (or maybe you can achieve it using JSON formatting).

**Documentation**: [List and library column types and options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7)

Comment: Thanks for answering. It was not clear for me if "cannot set null value AND show it as radio", I can't set a null value, or I can't set a null value AND display it as radio?

Comment: You have to set either "Yes" or "No" as a default values in column settings. So, you cannot set null value. Also, you cannot show this column as radio buttons as by default it is shown as single checkbox.

Comment: +one related question, id there is to import "Yes/No" from Excel, what shoul I put in the Excel column as text (Yes/No, or "1/0")?

Comment: With suggested choice column, use "Yes" or "No".